# link for download ooobasis3.4-core01

Tags: installation

when I was going to install `openoffice 3.4 sdk` I got an **error** `ooobasis3.4-core01 is not found`.

But I couldn't find a place where `ooobasis3.4-core01` can be downloaded. Can you give me a link which `ooobasis3.4-core01` can be downloaded?

Comment: You can download ooobasis3.4-core01 from this [website](http://sourceforge.net/projects/apacheoo-deb/files/debian/pool/main/o/).

Comment: @Mitch Thanks.but I tried on the link that you provided. but there the version of ooobasis3.4-core01 is 4.00. but i want the version 3.4.Do you know any more links?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a download link:

http://www.zerobit.in/ooo34/en-US/DEBS/ooobasis3.4-core01_3.4.0-1_i386.deb

Have a good day!

Comment: The above link is dead.